# How to compare sample and population characteristics?

Tags: sample, population, representative

I have a sample $S1$ of 200 people, and I obtained a subsample $S2$ of 100 people by emailing a survey link to $S1$. So, $S2$ is a nonrandom subsample drawn without replacement.

- In the sample $S1$, I know that 60 like apples, 60 like oranges, and
  80 like bananas.
- In the subsample $S2$, I found that 25 like apples,
  25 like oranges, and 50 like bananas.

How can I test the difference in fruit preferences between $S1$ and $S2$? They are obviously not independent, because there is overlap between the two samples. I don't know what statistical test to use.

Here is the dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
s1 <- tibble(fruit = c(rep("apple", 25), rep("orange", 25), rep("banana", 50)))
s2 <- tibble(fruit = c(rep("apple", 60), rep("orange", 60), rep("banana", 80)))
```

My guess is that I could run a chi-square test comparing the two groups?

```
chisq.test(table(s1$fruit), table(s2$fruit))
chisq.test(c(25, 25, 50), c(60, 60, 80)) # same as above
```

The result is:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  c(25, 25, 50) and c(60, 60, 80)
X-squared = 0.1875, df = 1, p-value = 0.665
```

Since p > .05, this test suggests that the two groups are not significantly different. Is this the right test to use and the right conclusion to draw?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "population sample"?  How would this differ from the *population* itself?

Comment: @whuber I clarified in my question that I have a sample S1 and a subsample S2. Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: That's hugely different!  I believe this has been asked (and answered) several times here, but the answer depends on how the subsample was obtained: was it with or without replacement?

Comment: @whuber I emailed a survey link to 200 people in the sample S1, and 100 people completed the survey. So, S2 is a nonrandom subsample drawn from S1 without replacement. I'm interested in knowing if S1 is different from S2, even though I already know that it's not (since it wasn't a random subsample).

Comment: That's important information which you should include in your question.  You have to apply a finite-population correction factor, so a standard $\chi^2$ test won't be right.

Comment: @whuber Thank you, that's very helpful information. I will look into a finite-population correction factor for my statistical test.